# How can I change the font size of a Swal2 Toast element title

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert2

I have been working on a project for some time, and researched one specific problem I have been unable to fix: changing the font size of a Swal2 Toast title. Everything functional works, but all the CSS solutions I have found do not work. The title of the modal is tiny and hard to read.

```
let message = getCookie("greeting");
        const Toast = Swal.mixin({
            timer: 3000,
            toast: true,
            position: "top-end",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            showClass: {
                popup: "animate__animated animate__fadeInRight",
            },
            hideClass: {
                popup: "animate__animated animate__fadeOutRight",
            },
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            allowEscapeKey: false,
        })
        Toast.fire({
            title: message,
        })
```

[image: image of modal]

Comment: there's got to be a solution somewhere...

Comment: ok, I guess there's no way to do that